# An elegant, neon-embellished installation of which...?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[The New Yorker](https://www.newyorker.com/goings-on-about-town/art/tom-sachs-8)

> After his recent move from Italy to Los Angeles the artist found himself creatively blocked, so he put aside painting and made wooden bows and arrows instead, an elegant, neon-embellished installation **of which** opens the show.

I want to comprehend the meaning of “of which” in the context, because I don’t know who is meant by “of which”.

Comment: of which refers to the bows and arrows. An installation of bows and arrows that opens the show.

Comment: Really! The comma separating the words “instead and elegant” tricked me, so I thought that “of which” wasn’t attached to bows or arrows. @Lambie

Comment: It's a relative construction where "of which" is the relative phrase. "Which" is complement to the preposition "of" and is anaphoric to "wooden bows and arrows".

Answer (score 2):

"Which" generally refers to the nearest preceding noun or noun phrase. Here, it refers to the wooden bows and arrows that the artist is now making.

Comment: Not quite: it is just "which" (not "of which") that has "wooden bows and arrows" as antecedent.